# Get stringValue from field of a document via REST API

Tags: json, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a `GET` call in this link:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectID}/databases/(default)/documents/
users/testers?key={MY_KEY}&fields=fields&mask.fieldPaths=ID
```

The answer it returns is:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "ID": {
      "stringValue": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change the link to get only `1` (or `{1}`) as answer from my GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Firebaser here]* that's not possible using the REST API. Firestore documents cannot be encoded as simple JSON objects since some types, such as advanced numeric types or `DocumentReference`, would be ambiguous when converted to strings or numbers.

Therefore the REST API encodes each field as a key-value pair with the type as the key.

The Firestore SDKs (which are available for most platforms) decode this for you and give you platform-native types.